# How to process every message in Openfire

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, multiplayer

I'm developing a multiplayer turn-based Android game. I'm using Openfire as the server and trying to process messages from user A to user B. But I couldnt find any listener to implement. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Edit: What I mean by "process message" is I use the body of the message to send special predefined commands to the server. For example if the user wants to make a guess in the game, body of the message packet would be something like "MAKE_GUESS Ohio". So I should be able to parse the body of the message for every packet and see if it's a special message packet.

Comment: Define what you mean by "process message"?  What do you need to accomplish in the server?

Comment: I got your meaning. Need a way to listen to all incoming messages, and parse the content. We can develop a plugin to do, but so far I don't have the detail solution.